# how to initiate pyautogui script [in the background]

Tags: windows, pyautogui

I just started learning Python, found out about pyautogui and I am eager to automate a couple of repetitive tasks.
However, in all the video tutorials on the topic the pyautogui script is initiated using an IDE/cmd, etc (Anaconda, Spyder) so the screen is "shared" between the IDE and the other application which we're automating.

The question is:

I write my cool .py script with pyautogui functionalities. How do I initiate this script in the background (or change the active window) so that the program being automated (i.e. web browser) is the only active (and maximized) window during the run-time.

The question is of more general nature but (hopefully) would be useful for other Python novices like myself)
Thank you in advance!
lakersbg

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, you can rename your .py file to .pyw to run it as a "windowless" script. Normally when you run Python scripts, a Command Prompt window will open, even if there's no stdout text that is printed. Using a .pyw will prevent this window from appearing.